# Can my company remove me from full time because I can’t do closing shifts

Tags: part-time, fulltime, company

My company decided they want more closing shifts managers but I can’t do those shifts because they end late at night, and you can be stuck there till 1am or later if the next person didn’t show up. I have 2 small kids that have school in the morning and bed time at 8pm.

I’ve been working with the company for years and now they have just decided this. When I said I couldn’t close they decided I would be part time meaning I lose all my benefits.

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in? If the answer is "most of the US", yes, they can do just about anything they like. Welcome to the Land of the Free.

Comment: In addition to the above - what does your contract say? If it sets a work schedule or doesn't specify a closing shift, you may have some leverage.

Comment: Just you or are they doing this to others?

Comment: If you can't meet the requirements of the job role, you need to expect something to change

Comment: Pretty sure what they are doing conflicts with the "Unlawful Disparate Treatment of Workers with Caregiving Responsibilities" act... Which is Title VII, Rehabilitation Act, ADA, 29 CFR Part 1604, 29 CFR Part 1630...


And basically makes discrimanting against someone because they have caregiving responsibilities illegal..

Comment: @cdkMoose as Ann Rose woas working at the job during the day shift. While here children was fully looked after.. She was capable of doing the job... It is her employers decision to stick a caregiver who has care giving responsibilities in the evening... into an evening role that has caused an issue...  Its totally unfair and should be illegal... I honestly believe that shift work where they can assign you whatever hours they want should be illegal unless they pay half time during any/all hours that you could possibly work. As you are 'on call' during those hours.

Comment: @Questor, OP did not indicate that she is the only one being asked to work closing shifts. in fact it reads to me like a shared responsibility, so it is not disparate or unfair to ask people in the same role to do the same job.  It is not the legal responsibility of the employer to give her an easier job for the same role just because she has kids.  Sometimes our personal situations don't match the  needs of the job, it is not the responsibility of the employer to adjust the needs of the job to fit our situation.

Comment: @cdkMoose employers by law in the US are required to make reasonable accommodations to caregivers... Allowing a caregiver to keep their current shift instead of forcing them to work in a different shift is a reasonable accommodation. It is required by law.

Comment: @cdkMoose and they are reuiqred by law to make reasonable accomadations t oprimary caregivers in terms of unpaid leave/reduced hours etc... Of course required by law only works if you are a) aware of the law and b) exercise your right under the law... Most employers asume that their employees don't know the law, and will find it to onerous to exercise their rights under the law, or themselves don't know the law.

Comment: @questor, not all countries legally require reasonable accommodations for primary caregivers.  And in your comment you even indicate reduced hours which is what is happening to OP

Answer (score 3):

If they can fire you outright (and you haven't given us any reason they couldn't), they can certainly reduce your shifts by threatening you with that alternative.

Maybe you can reach an agreement with them that the extra inconvenience and responsibility should mean you get a pay increase. That's not what you say you want, but it's better than nothing.

If you can't reach an agreement with them, your only recourse may be to start looking for a job elsewhere that's a better fit to your needs. Don't quit this job until you have a committed start date at the new business, in writing if possible; not enough hours still pays better than no hours.

Comment: While not technically wrong, it sounds a bit like having no protections from being fired on a whim is the norm. "Any reason" could as well be "I live outside the US". That happens to be the case for a lot of people.

Comment: @nvoigt True in general, but it is rather 'I live in Europe' instead of 'I live outside of the US'. US plus Europe covers a large proportion of all SE users but the remaining parts of the world are closer to US laws than EU laws in this respect.

Comment: I can't advise on non-US business practices. (I won't _touch_ India's work rules; I understand just enough to know I'll never understand them.) But the point remains that if you are working shifts you are at risk of being put on a shift you don't like, and you don't usually have the right to demand that someone else accept it. And being guaranteed a number of hours of work does not guarantee specific hours unless that is written into the contract. I think an employer could say that if you aren't working assigned hours they aren't obligated to give you other hours. Negotiate, tolerate, or exit.